# MDC Web Textfield component outline disappearing

Tags: javascript, material-design, textfield, mdc-components

I am having an issue with MDC web textfield component. The issue is that the outline does not stay when I click on the textfield to type in an input. See below for the pug and javascript code :

```
div.mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4.mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-12-phone.mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-12-tablet
  label.mdc-text-field.mdc-text-field--filled
    span.mdc-text-field__ripple
    span.mdc-floating-label(id="first_name") First Name :
    input.mdc-text-field__input(type="text" aria-labelledby="first_name")
    span.mdc-line-ripple
div.mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4.mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-12-phone.mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-12-tablet
  label.mdc-text-field.mdc-text-field--outlined
    span.mdc-notched-outline
    span.mdc-notched-outline__leading
    span.mdc-notched-outline__notch
      span.mdc-floating-label(id="last_name") Surname :
    span.mdc-notched-outline__trailing
  input.mdc-text-field__input(type="text" aria-labelledby="last_name")
```

````
const textFields = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-text-field'), function (el) {
    return new mdc.textField.MDCTextField(el);
});

const notchedOutline = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-notched-outline'), function (el) {
    return new mdc.notchedOutline.MDCNotchedOutline(el);

});

const floatingLabel = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-floating-label'), function (el) {
    return new mdc.floatingLabel.MDCFloatingLabel(el);

});

const lineRipple = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-line-ripple'), function (el) {
    return new mdc.lineRipple.MDCLineRipple(el);

});
```[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8t9g.png
````

Answer (score 0):

The primary color of the website was white and this made it look as though it disappeared when it was actually just white. When you change the primary color  of the website, it reflects on the textfield as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).